# Finding if point is in polygon then taking attribute from polygon dataframe and inserting it as a column in the point dataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, time, iteration, geodataframe

I'm doing some GIS analysis in Python for COVID work. I've geocoded our entire membership (gdf_schoolAgedChildren) base and captured their locations in a shapely point data type (for each member). I've also obtained the polygon shapes of school district boundaries (schoolDistricts) and those are stored as shapely polygon data types.

What I am attempting to do is:

1. Iterate over each point data in gdf_schoolAgedChildren
2. Iterate polygons (schoolDistricts) to check and to see if that point is within any of the polygon data points in
3. If the point is within that polygon: I want to take the school district name (from schoolDistricts) and enter it as a column in  gdf_schoolAgedChildren.

The code I have currently is:

```py
for index, row in gdf_schoolAgedChildren.iterrows(): 
    point = row["geometry"]
    for num, ob in schoolDistricts.iterrows(): 
        if point.within(ob["geometry"]): 
             gdf_schoolAgedChildren["District Name"] = ob["DistricName"]
```

I'm processing about 2 million data points and have come to find that using the iterrows will make this painstakingly long. Anyone privy to a workaround to speed this up?

**End Goal**: Once I append the District Names to gdf_schoolAgedChildren() I need to use that column to pull in the Polygon data points from schoolDistricts back into gdf_schoolAgedChildren. I need the gdf_schoolAgedChildren to have district names, district polygon data, and counts of each point within each polygon shape.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Long compound titles generally mean the the question is not focused enough for our Focused question/Best answer model. In this case, the question is nearly focused enough (above the End Goal), so the title is misleading (the question is about optimizing the query, which needs to be done through some sort of indexing algorithm; what you do after that is really beyond the scope). Generally speaking, searching points with polygons will be faster than searching polygons by points, so invert your `for` loops.

Answer (score 3):

Use spatial join / sjoin:

```
import geopandas as gpd

pointdf = gpd.read_file(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\bs_riks_sample.shp')
polydf = gpd.read_file(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\ak_riks_2.shp')
polyfield = 'KOMMUNKOD' #Field to join to the points

joined = gpd.sjoin(left_df=pointdf, right_df=polydf, how='left') #Join
joined = [col for col in joined.columns if col in pointdf.columns or col == polyfield] #Keep all point columns and "polyfield"
```